# HTTP_HOST error with Django

Tags: django

I keep getting the following error:

```
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '*.mydomain.com'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035.
```

I get this on my page when the user is integrating their account with Google Calendar (when the redirect happens from Google). I added the following to my `settings.py`:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

Why am I keep getting this error? I read the documentation on django docs and it clearly says this setting should be fine. I read the following page for this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/

and the source:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/request.py

Comment: You're getting this error because this function doesn't view the * as a valid part of the domain. https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/request.py#L530

Comment: how can I circumvent this? This happens with Google Calendar redirect when we get a response. The response is successful, but I also get this error. Seems like with Google we're doing things correctly.

Comment: It looks like you shouldn't use the wildcard.

Comment: You were right! I set the `REFERRERS` in Google API Console to `www.mydomain.com/*`. If you put the answer below i'll accept.

Comment: Glad you were able to get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting this error because this [function](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/request.py#L530) doesn't view the * as a valid part of the domain. You can get around this by not using the wildcard in your Google API Console (as you said).